# Slide a div up to match its new contents with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that contains questions

> Questions 2:
>           What is the square root of 16?
>
> ```
> A. 7
> B. 5
> C. 4
> D. 1
> ```

I need to make it so when an answer choice is selected, it slides up and shows:

> ```
> QUESTION 2: Correct! (Or Incorrect!)
> ```

I have it all working using the Javascript here:

```
function finalizeAnswer(bttn,c,questionId) {
    if (c) {
        bttn.parentNode.style.backgroundColor="lightgreen";
        bttn.parentNode.innerHTML="<b>QUESTION "+(questionId+1)+":</b> Correct!";
    } else {
        bttn.parentNode.style.backgroundColor="pink";
        bttn.parentNode.innerHTML="<b>QUESTION "+(questionId+1)+":</b> Wrong!";
    }
    updateScore();
}
```

The div resizes because its contents are different (no longer a long question, just a short response).  Would it be possible to replace something in here to make it slide up instead of just popping up?

Just for reference for the function I included:

> bttn -> The button that was pressed. (A, B, C, or D)
>
> c -> If the answer was correct
>
> questionId -> Used to get data about the question.
>
> updateScore(); -> just a function that updates the score on the quiz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution uses jQuery to animate the change in height.

**EDIT**: I've updated this to use the true new height instead of a magically guessed at 24px.

**[See Live Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GFnnc/14/)**

```
function displayResult(container, correct, questionId){ 

    // Keep up with the old height
    var oldHeight = $(container).height();

    // Change the contents
    $(container).css('background-color', correct == true ? 'lightgreen' : 'pink');
    $(container).html("<b>QUESTION " + (questionId+ 1) + ":</b> " + (correct == true ? "Correct!" : "Wrong!"));    

    // Capture the new height
    var newHeight = $(container).height();

    // Jump back to the old height and then animate to the new
    $(container).css('height', oldHeight);
    $(container).animate({height:newHeight});
}

function finalizeAnswer(bttn,c,questionId) {
    displayResult(bttn.parentNode, c, questionId);

    // I have commented out the call to updateScore since I don't have it
    //updateScore();
}
```

Comment: Note that you can control the speed of the animation, e.g., $(container).animate({height:'24px'}, 2000); would make it last two seconds.

Comment: Thanks so much!  Points for you!  I hereby deem this question... ANSWERED!